# junit unique xml output name

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to output a unique ID from junit tests. Since we have multiple build boxes running unit tests on different release versions.  But I want todir= to be in the same folder.

```
<target name="test" depends="compileTest">
    <junit fork="yes" forkmode="once" failureproperty="test.failure">
      <classpath path="${TomcatClassPath};${TestClassPath};${TestBuildDir};${buildDir}"/>
      <formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />
      <batchtest todir="${unitTestReultDir}">
          <fileset dir="${TestSrcDir}">
          </fileset>
      </batchtest>
    </junit>
    <fail message="test failed" if="test.failure">
    </fail>
</target>
```

Always outputs:
TEST-com.company.app.component.ClassNameTest.xml

Would Like:
TEST-com.company.app.component.ClassNameTest_YYYYMMDDHHMMSSmmmm.xml

Is there a way to append a timestamp to prevent files from overwriting each other.

Comment: You should edit your question, and post your code there.

Comment: @TXN_747 edit your question, otherwise it wont be clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `<formatter type="xml" extension="${timestamp}.xml"/>`. This should append the timestamp variable to the test result file name. Note: `timestamp` is a variable that you will have to define.